# Helm 3 installation error through proxy server

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

Does anyone know why helm 3 install occurs error through proxy server?

**Environment:**

OS:         Ubuntu 18.04

Kubernetes: v1.19.0

Helm:       v3.3.4

```
root@ecs-k8s-master:~# kubectl cluster-info
Kubernetes master is running at https://192.168.30.5:6443
KubeDNS is running at https://192.168.30.5:6443/api/v1/namespaces/kube-system/services/kube-dns:dns/proxy

root@ecs-k8s-master:~# https_proxy=http://172.19.1.222:3128 helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx
Error: Kubernetes cluster unreachable: Get "https://192.168.30.5:6443/version?timeout=32s": Forbidden
```

Comment: Helm (3) and `kubectl` use the same mechanisms to talk to the cluster.  If you don't need `$http_proxy` for one then you don't need it for the other.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your proxy server either does require authentication or does not allow the connection to your cluster as it tells you "forbidden".